# Flutter - Google Mobile Ads - Ads are getting disappear after few seconds

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-mobile-ads

Test ads are getting disappeared automatically after few seconds and getting below logs:

```
I/Ads     (24763): This request is sent from a test device.
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(24763): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.CACHE
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(24763): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START
D/EgretLoader(24763): EgretLoader(Context context)
D/EgretLoader(24763): The context is not activity
I/DynamiteModule(24763): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:231004600
I/DynamiteModule(24763): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 231004600
W/ContentCatcher(24763): Failed to notify a WebView
W/ContentCatcher(24763): Failed to notify a WebView
D/Surface (24763): lockHardwareCanvas
W/chromium(24763): [WARNING:display_webview.cc(32)] WebView overlays are enabled!
E/FrameEvents(24763): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/GED     (24763): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 27, oppidx_max 27, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     (24763): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 27, oppidx_max 27, oppidx_min 0
D/Surface (24763): lockHardwareCanvas
E/FrameEvents(24763): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
W/ContentCatcher(24763): Failed to notify a WebView
```

Package used:
[google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads)

Configurations are the same as in the documentation.

Ads must not be disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following meta-data inside the  tag in your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data 
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
   android:value="ca-app-pub-[your id]" />
```

if you are using Android 12 or 13, add the following line after the  tag if already added ignore it

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.YOUR_AD_ID"/>
```

uninstall and install your app

check if your id is active or not in admob

turn off any adbloker or adbloking dns

Comment: Thank You for your response. I have Android 11 so no need to add ```<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.YOUR_AD_ID"/>``` line. Ads still getting disappear after few seconds.